# Is there a way to create a url vCard with a description below it and share it using swift 4?... iOS Maps do it sharing a marked location

Tags: ios, swift, location, sharing, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to share a location through vCard like this:

```
var vCardString = [
    "BEGIN:VCARD",
    "VERSION:4.0",
    "N:;Shared Location;;;",
    "FN:Shared Location",
    "item1.URL:http://maps.apple.com/?ll=\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)",
    "item1.X-ABLabel:map url",
    "END:VCARD"
    ].joined(separator: "\n")

let myData = vCardString.data(using: .utf8)! as NSData
var items = [Any]()
let vCardActivity = NSItemProvider(item: myData!, typeIdentifier: kUTTypeVCard as String)
items.append(vCardActivity)
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
present(activityViewController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

This actually works but I cannot add a description below the vCard...

[I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRzg4.jpg)

[I'm looking for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXef4.jpg)

I've tried adding another item:

```
var items = [Any]()
let vCardActivity = NSItemProvider(item: myData!, typeIdentifier: kUTTypeVCard as String)
items.append(vCardActivity)
let myTitle = "This is my title"
items.append(myTitle)
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
present(activityViewController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

But it only shows the vCard

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you add an address field to the VCard?

Like this:

```
let vCardString = [
        "BEGIN:VCARD",
        "VERSION:4.0",
        "N:;Shared Location;;;",
        "FN:Shared Location",
        "ADR;TYPE=HOME;LABEL=42 Plantation St. Baytown, LA 30314 United States of America:;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America",
        "item1.URL:http://maps.apple.com/?ll=25.686613,-100.316116",
        "item1.X-ABLabel:map url",
        "END:VCARD"
        ].joined(separator: "\n")
```

You will get something like this:

[image]

Comment: I added the item1.URL:https://google.com/maps/@lat,long to the vCard, but scanning the card opens the map according to the address given in the ADR attribute instead of the one in the geolocation. In my case, there is a difference of about half a mile between the two.